# How to set neovim to run a qt-console

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, neovim

I am trying to configure neovim for python programming. I found [this article](https://www.blog.gambitaccepted.com/2020/04/26/neovim-qtconsole-setup/)  about how to connect qt-console to a python script with neovim as editor, everything I could ask for.

I followed the steps and my `init.vim` looks like this

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'bfredl/nvim-ipy'
call plug#end()

command! -nargs=0 RunQtConsole
\call jobstart("jupyter qtconsole --JupyterWidget.include_other_output=True")

let g:ipy_celldef = '^##' " regex for cell start and end

nmap <silent> <leader>jqt :RunQtConsole<Enter>
nmap <silent> <leader>jk :IPython<Space>--existing<Space>--no-window<Enter>
nmap <silent> <leader>jc <Plug>(IPy-RunCell)
nmap <silent> <leader>ja <Plug>(IPy-RunAll)
```

also, my `ftplugin/python.vim` looks like this

```
setlocal tabstop=4
setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal expandtab
setlocal autoindent
```

but using `<leader>jqt` gives the following error

`E492: not an editor command:jobstart("jupyter qtconsole --JupyterWidget.include_other_output=True")`

My guess is that this is because `RunQtConsole` assumes that you already activated and enviroment where jupyter is installed. So I tried to launch nvim in a python enviroment but the result is the same.

Later, I tried to perform a enviroment activation from the nvim terminal (and then `RunQtCOnsole`), but didn't figure how to do this.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it all on a single line:

```
command! -nargs=0 RunQtConsole call jobstart("jupyter qtconsole --JupyterWidget.include_other_output=True")
```

Or if you want to use separate lines add a space after the `\`:

```
command! -nargs=0 RunQtConsole
  \ call jobstart("jupyter qtconsole --JupyterWidget.include_other_output=True")
```

Comment: With this command, the newly launched QtConsole will get the focus. How can I modify this command to let my terminal keep the focus?

Comment: Same here, someone know how to do this modification?

Comment: I have had the same problem. It seems to be first option - that worked for me.